# Easy RegEx expression for someone who knows regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, coldfusion

I know very little about regex so this has proven very challenging for me.

I have a form that I need to make sure only contains A-Z or a-z or 1-0 and a few other "approved" characters and the ' ' (space).  When spelled out, I only want to allow for:

```
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 /:;,.-()`
```

From another stackoverflow question, I did find this regex:
    `^((?:[A-Za-z0-9-'.,@:?!()$#/\\]+|&[^#])*&?)$`
but I think it is allowing for too many special characters and also in the notes, someone commented about c# so I'm not sure if it is applicable in the way I'm trying to use it.  I'm using coldfusion, jquery, and javascript.  I'm actually using a jQuery plug-in that I'm trying to add a validation rule for (plug-in is http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

An example of an INvalid entry into the form is:
MC&I Enterprise
but MC/I is acceptable

Can some one help?

Comment: Here you can learn more about regexes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: b-mitch thanks for adding that tag
Martinho-Fernandes thanks for the link

Comment: Could you turn the title of your question into an actual question and be specific about your question.This makes it easier to understand and search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start practicing with regex's, you may consider downloading the regex coach: http://weitz.de/regex-coach/ it's a free program that explains regex's and allows to see how the regex parsing works.

You may start using the `\w` shorthand: it matches any so-called "word character", that is `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_` (but it does not include any kind of whitespace); then you can add all the characters you need to the character class.

If "_" (underscore) is in the list of the allowed characters, you could use this regex (that allows an empty string):

```
^[\w ()/:;,.-]*$
```

Or, if you want to validate only non-empty strings, you could use this one (which has the + sign instead of the *, meaning respectively "match one or more characters" and "match zero or more characters"):

```
^[\w ()/:;,.-]+$
```

If "_" (underscore) is **not** in the list of the allowed characters, then you have to use the intervals explicitly:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d ()/:;,.-]*$
```

or

```
^[a-zA-Z\d ()/:;,.-]+$
```

Comment: Don't forget \w matches _ which is not in the list of allowed chars

Comment: @paolo-stefan All the answers were valid, but I accepted this one since it explains more of the solution than just the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The following should do:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9\ /:;,\.\-\(\)]*$'
```

I don't think the colon, comma, or semicolon need to be escaped, but if it gives you trouble, add a backslash in front of those, too.  Some of the other escapes may be overkill, but shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: Perhaps + instead of * to avoid matching an empty string?

Comment: For this character class, the only char needing an escape is the `"-"`. (And not even that if it is placed at beginning or end of the class.)

Comment: Thanks ridgerunner, I tend to err on the side of over escaping things.  @Alex K. I should have pointed that out, it's completely up to dlackey as to what he's willing to accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically convert you list of approved characters into a character class like so:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 /:;,.\-()]+$
```

That should only match if the full text contains only the characters on your allowed list (more complicated rules, e.g. no spaces on the end, etc. might require a more regular expression.

[This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is an extremely useful introduction to regular expressions.

Comment: At the very least, wouldn't you need to escape the `-`?